# how to create manual reports and graphical represntation as content type

Tags: database

Hello guys any Module which can provide tools so that we can manually input data and output them as graphical representation. I have tried Data visualization module but its complex to add JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use any of these modules :

1. [Google Analytics Report](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports)

> Google Analytics Reports provides graphical reporting of your site's
>   tracking data. Graphical reports include a dashboard widget for
>   admins, a small path-based report in blocks, and a full path-based
>   report.

2. [Forena Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena)

> Forena is database report writing software built on the Drupal
>   platform. Forena is built of the idea that if you can write the SQL
>   necessary to get the data out of a database, it should take very
>   little work to get that data out on the web. It is designed to
>   leverage knowledge of HTML, CSS, SQL and Java Script to help you
>   create rich interactive web reports.

3. [Charts & Graphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts_graphs)

> Charts and Graphs is an API for developers. It can easily be extended
>   by third-party modules that want to add their own charting
>   implementations. It does nothing by itself.

Comment: Thanks NishantP, I will have a look, already installed charts and Graphs module lets see how forena works

Comment: Anyway forena needs lots of work to be done, its cant create chart/graph.

Comment: Have you try Google Analytics Report module ?

Comment: I think I didn't explain you well, suppose I have a shirt in three colors and I wanted to create report the color popularity weekly-monthly-yearly basis and then to render them in graphical way

Comment: I have understand what you are asking for. I think any of these module can solve your issue. I think Charts & Graphs module are do the same that you want.

Comment: Anyway I have tried dataviz, chart module, I have created taxonomy field with the name top, with terms- shirt, t shirt, x, y now another field is date, data percentage(integer field) now created views for that but the problem is its not pulling all the taxonomy terms even I have selected all in multifield settings. Any solution for that?